# NSObject subclass as File's Owner in IOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Does Apple say anywhere in the docs that you should be subclassing UIViewController (or one of its subclasses) for the File's Owner in xib files?

In Mac OS programming I use NSObject subclassed objects as file owners all the time. Has that changed for iOS? I can't seem find any reason not to but seeing [super viewDidLoad] in UIViewController subclasses made me think of this since you dont need to call [super awakeFromNib] in OSX programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIViewController` is an abstract class: it's meant to be subclassed and used as a File's Owner. It's got very nice features for views. I recommend you not to use `awakeFromNib` in favor of `viewDidLoad` and others.

I hope Mac OS X gets view controllers too. Window controllers ain't right yet.

Comment: that still doesn't say if subclassing NSObject shouldn't be done... Also, OSX has view controllers (NSViewController)

Comment: But I want more advanced view controllers, like those in iOS.

Comment: Subclassing `NSObject` doesn't give you the advanced features of `UIViewController`, but it's totally allowed.

Comment: great. So it's missing features like presentModalViewController: that helps a lot.